# Dynamically name views

Tags: java, android

I've learned how to create views dynamically, but  is it possible to NAME them dynamically? For example, how can I create, say, 3 TextViews named "myTV1", "myTV2" and "myTV3" using a for loop?

Comment: not much of an android dev, but if it isn't api supported, it's probably reflection supported in some way

Comment: No, it's not reflection supported -- you cannot create dynamically created names for variables in Java, and more importantly, nor do you want to.

Comment: Variable "names" aren't really all that important, don't exist for many objects, and *almost* don't exist in compiled code. And if an object is referred to by several variables, which one represents the "name" for this object? Much more important are *object **references*** and how they can be obtained.

Comment: If you must associate an object with a String, a clean way to do this is by using a Map such as a `HashMap<String, MyType>` or `HashMap<MyType, String>` depending on which you desire to use as the key, but again don't put too much reliance on variable names since non-final variables can change references at the drop of a hat, and objects can be referred to by more than one variable.

Comment: Or if you want to associate your variable with monotonically increasing numbers, then use an ArrayList.

Comment: You can Set TAG value for dynamic views.